# Sorting JSON by Multiple Keys with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have been searching this site for the *best* way for me to sort my JSON data. Unfortunately I have only been able to find answers showing the sorting of a basic JSON data set. Often these answers only sort by one piece of information.

I would like to be able to sort a more complex JSON data set and do it by multiple keys/columns with the first sort key taking preference over the second and so on.

```
{
  'files' : [ 
    {
      'type a' : [
        {
          '20200101' : [
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            },
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          '20200102' : [
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            },
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      'type b' : [
        {
          '20200101' : [
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            },
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            }
          ],
          '20200102' : [
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            },
            {
              'title' : *some_title*
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to sort the above JSON array in multiple ways.

- type then date then title
- date then type then title

In the past I have just been using `array_multisort()` on much more basic JSON data similar to:

```
$json[$n] = array(
          'file':*sample*,
          'date':*sample*,
          'title':*sample*
        );

array_multisort(
    array_column($json, 'file'), SORT_ASC,
    array_column($json, 'date'), SORT_ASC, 
    array_column($json, 'title'), SORT_ASC, 
    $json
);
```

I believe (please correct me if I am wrong) that it would be better to store my data in a JSON similar to the one at the top of the question. Which may provide some performance increase and if not it will at least be best practice.

**How could I best sort JSON data by multiple keys or values?**

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Seems to me you could just sort each level separately, treating as simple JSON (sort each file by type, then type by date, then date by title).